# Fractional Linear Transformations and their matrix form

Tags: complex-analysis

For $z \in \mathbb{C}$, a fractional linear transformation of $z$, with an associated matrix $M$ is:
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \\ T_{M}(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz+d}.$$

However, I don't see how we can use the matrix $M$ to gain the transformation.
In Linear Algebra, I learnt that linear transformations will always have some matrix $A$ w.r.t to ordered bases in the domain and codomain. In particular, if the bases are the same and in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then we have
$\forall v \in D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2, T(v) = Av$.

I don't see how we can multiply $M$ to gain a *fraction* for the fractional linear transformation.

Comment: What you're asking is rather obscure.Why do you want to multiply $M$ for?

Comment: Ah I shouldn't have included that in. It's because in Linear Algebra, we would always (I think) multiply the vector (or coordinate vector) we want to transform with its transformation (as a matrix). I'm not sure how we can use $M$ to transform $z$

Comment: If you have $M$ you have its 4 coefficients. The first row gives the coefficients of the numerator, the second row those of the denominator. Where's the problem?

Comment: If you treat $\mathbb C$ as a subset of a one-dimensional complex projective space $\{(z,w), (z,w)\ne0\}$ then multiplying by $M$ gives exactly your fractional linear transform in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Which operation is it that matrix representation should help out with? I would guess composition, but I am not sure.

Comment: I'm not quite sure; because when given the matrix of some linear transformation in Linear Algebra, I'd always think of multiplying the vector to be transformed with it. I was thinking that since the given $M$ here was also a linear map, I could take some coordinate vector and multiply $M$ with it, but the result wouldn't be a fraction.  
e.g. Finding the matrix for the derivative map of $\mathbb{P}_2$ to $\mathbb{P}_2$ with ordered standard bases is a familiar case

Comment: You should look at the [projective line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_line) $P^1(\mathbb{C})$, the set of couples of complex numbers $[z:w]$ with the projective equivalence $[z:w] = [\lambda z: \lambda w] = [\frac{z}{w}:1]$. Let a matrix $\gamma \in GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ acts as usual by $$\gamma [z:w] = [az+bw: cz+dw], \quad \text{ then } \quad \gamma [z:1] = [\frac{az+b}{cz+d}:1]$$ and obviously everything works well with the multiplication of matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "fractional linear transformation" is not a special kind of "linear transformation", so you'll have to unlearn a little bit of linear algebra to understand this issue.

Let's take apart the definitions to see what a fractional linear transformation actually is.

Start with the matrix $M = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$.

When we think of $M$ as a "linear transformation", that means that $M$ is treated as a function
$$L_M : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2
$$
where the elements of the domain and range of $L_M$ are vectors --- more specifically, column vectors. As you say, this function is evaluated by matrix multiplication, where the four coefficients of the matrix $M$ are applied with the following effect: if $v = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ then
$$L_M(v) =  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ax+by \\ cx+dy \end{pmatrix}
$$

When we think of $M$ as a "fractional linear transformation", we do **not** think of it as a function where the elements of the domain and range are vectors. Instead, $M$ is treated as a function where the elements of the domain and range are complex numbers:
$$T_M : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}
$$
This function is *not* a linear transformation of any kind, and it is *not* evaluated by any kind of matrix multiplication (at least, not at first...). Instead, it is evaluted by this formula, where the four coefficients of the matrix are applied to a different effect:
$$T_M(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}
$$
(One caveat: the domain and range should really be the extended complex numbers $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$, with appropriate formulas to interpret "infinity arithmetic")

So, was this terminology just pulled out of a hat? Why did someone decide to call this a "fractional linear transformation"?

The reason is that you can break the evaluation of $T_M(z)$ into a multi-step process in which you take "the fraction of a linear transformation". What I really mean by these words is simply that you do this:

1. Write $z$ as a fraction: $z = \frac{u}{v}$. For example, you could choose $u=z$ and $v=1$, or you could choose $v$ to be any complex number whatsoever and take $u=zv$. The final outcome of this multi-step process will be well-defined independent of choice.
2. Treating the numerator and denominator separately, write them as components of a column matrix: $\begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \end{pmatrix}$.
3. Apply $M$ as a *linear transformation*, using this column matrix as the input, producing the output
   $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} au+bv \\ cu+dv \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   (Another caveat: $M$ is being treated as a linear transformation over the complex numbers, instead of just over the real numbers.)
4. Treat the the components of the output column matrix as a fraction and then do a little fraction arithmetic:
   $$\frac{au+bv}{cu+dv} = \frac{au+bv}{cu+dv} \cdot \frac{1/v}{1/v} = \frac{a\frac{u}{v} + b}{c \frac{u}{v} + d} = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}
   $$
   Voila!

Answer (score 3):

It's a 2-by-2 complex matrix. It defines a linear map from $\Bbb C^2$
to $\Bbb C^2$. Therefore it defines a map from the projective line
$\Bbb P^1(\Bbb C)$ to itself. We can think of this projective line as
$\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}$. So $M$ induces a map from 
$\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ to itself. That map is $T_M$.

Comment: Clearly the OP doesn't know the projective space (most people learn it with the Möbius transformations)

Answer (score 1):

To try and reduce the complexity a bit from these very technical answers you have had.

Multiplication carries out concatenation. $M_1M_2$ will correspond to $T_{M_1}\circ T_{M_2} = T_{M_1}(T_{M_2}(z))$

So the matrix maps the function itself so that matrix multiplication gives the same effect as function concatenation.

Matrix multiplication figures out the new constants for us in a new fractional transform that would carry out the same as both the factors would in a row.

Just to demonstrate it works:

$$T_1(z) = \frac{a_1z+b_1}{c_1z+d_1}\,,\,T_2(z) = \frac{a_2z+b_2}{c_2z+d_2}$$

$$T_2(T_1(z)) = \frac{a_2\frac{a_1z+b_1}{c_1z+d_1}+b_2}{c_2\frac{a_1z+b_1}{c_1z+d_1}+d_2} = /\text{mul w. } c_1z+d_1 / = \frac{a_2(a_1z+b_1)+b_2(c_1z+d_1)}{c_2(a_1z+b_1)+d_2(c_1z+d_1)} =\\= \frac{(a_2a_1+b_2c_1)z+a_2b_1+b_2d_1}{(c_2a_1+d_2c_1)z+c_2b_1+d_2d_1}$$

Now with matrices:

$$M_{T_1} = \left[\begin{array}{rr}a_1&b_1\\c_1&d_1\end{array}\right]\,,\,M_{T_2} = \left[\begin{array}{rr}a_2&b_2\\c_2&d_2\end{array}\right]$$

And the product:

$$M_{T_2}M_{T_1} = \left[\begin{array}{rr}a_1a_2+b_2c_1&a_2b_1+b_2d_1\\a_1c_2+c_1d_2&c_2b_1+d_2d_1\end{array}\right]$$

Now we can identify the elements of the matrix and the position of the constants and see they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just an add-on to previous answers and comments:

The fractional linear transformation (a.k.a. *homography* on $\mathbf P^1(\mathbf C)$ is not really represented by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbf C)$, but by it equivalence class modulo scalar multiplication, i.e. it is an element of the *projective linear group* $\;\operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbf C)$.