# Is there a simple way to interpolate smoothly between levels of a complex-valued continued fraction?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, continued-fractions, smooth-functions

I have two complex numbers, $a = x_1 + y_1 i$ and $b = x_2 + y_2 i$. These serve as inputs to an infinite continued fraction of the form $f_n = a + \frac{b}{f_{n - 1}}$, with $f_1 = a$. Thus the first few levels of the continued fraction are:

- $f_1 = a$
- $f_2 = a + \frac{b}{a} = \frac{a^2 + b}{a}$
- $f_3 = a + \frac{b}{a + \frac{b}{a}} = \frac{a^3 + 2 a b}{a^2 + b}$
- $f_4 = a + \frac{b}{a + \frac{b}{a + \frac{b}{a}}} = \frac{a^4 + 3 a^2 b + b^2}{a^3 + 2 a b}$
- $f_5 = a + \frac{b}{a + \frac{b}{a + \frac{b}{a + \frac{b}{a}}}} = \frac{a^5 + 4 a^3 b + 3 a b^2}{a^4 + 3 a^2 b + b^2}$

For most values of $a$ and $b$, the values of $f_n$ spiral around a fixed point $M = \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 + 4 b}}{2}$, getting ever closer as $n$ increases.

[image: Graph of the continued-fraction points connected by vectors]

With only the points or the points-and-vectors visible, the spiral isn't always obvious, but connecting the points with circular arcs makes it more apparent:

[image: Graph of the continued-fraction points connected by circular arcs]

However, while it isn't difficult to construct circular arcs with positional continuity ($C^0$ & $G^0$, so there are no gaps between points) and tangent continuity ($G^1$, so the tangents of the circular arcs which meet at each point are the same), that is as far as the continuity goes. The piecewise arcs do not make up a smooth function which interpolates meaningfully between the points.

I want to find a function $f(x) = z$ with a real-valued input $x$ and complex-valued output $z$ which passes through $a$ at $f(1)$ and all subsequent points at their respective index values, so $f_n = f(n)$ and which ideally is infinitely-differentiable ([smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness)) everywhere, except at $f(0)$ which is undefined due to division by zero.

Is that even possible? If so, how do I find that function? If not, are there alternatives?

**Update:** While struggling to understand MathWonk's answer, I realized that I don't need to understand all the underlying mechanics if WolframAlpha can handle it for me. The key insight that MathWonk provided is that $z ↦ a + \frac{b}{z}$ can be rewritten as $z ↦ \frac{a z + b}{1 z + 0}$, which is the standard form of a linear fractional transformation $z ↦ \frac{a z + b}{c z + d}$ with $c = 1$ and $d = 0$. This corresponds to the $2 × 2$ matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}a & b \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$. The left column of the $n$th integer power of that matrix corresponds to the numerator and denominator of the $n$th level of my continued fraction. Asking WolframAlpha to evaluate the expression $((a, b), (1, 0))^x$ produces a complicated output matrix which, using the knowledge that the left two entries in the output matrix are the numerator and denominator of the continued fraction at input-value $x$, simplifies to $\frac{(λ_1 - λ_2) λ_2^t}{λ_1^t - λ_2^t} + λ_1$, where $λ_1 = \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 + 4 b}}{2}$ and $λ_2 = \frac{a - \sqrt{a^2 + 4 b}}{2}$. Plotting that expression in the complex plane gives the following graph, which is exactly what I wanted:

[image: Graph of the continued-fraction points connected by circular arcs with a spiraling, smooth function overlaid on top.]

I'll probably keep trying to figure out how the linear-algebra magic works under the hood to produce that answer, since I like to know what's actually going on to produce useful solutions, but it's nice to have a concrete result!

Comment: Yes, I believe its possible assuming $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n^s}$ converges for $\Re(s)\ge 2$, but the function I have in mind doesn't evaluate to a spiral analogous to your second figure. The function I have in mind is based on my answer to a question on an entire function interpolating the Möbius function $\mu(n)$ (see my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4160465). Let me know if you want me to post an answer here with the specific details related to your question.

Comment: @StevenClark Most of the terminology and symbols in the answer you linked are going right over my head, I'm afraid, but I think I at least understand the pictures. If the function you have in mind would have the same high-frequency oscillations between the integer-input points for my continued fractions as it does in the answer you linked, it probably isn't what I'm looking for, but I admit I'm curious what it would actually look like if you want to try applying it anyway.

Comment: When I generated a parametric plot of the analytic version of $f(x)$ in your question above, it seemed to return to the origin (or at least close to the origin) between consecutive integer values of $x$. Do you want me to post an answer with the related formulas and some graphics?

Comment: @StevenClark I don't think that's what I'm looking for, but if nothing else works I might come back to you.

Comment: Ok, I'm curious what the result will look like related to the answer posted below and how it will compare to my result.

Comment: @StevenClark I got it figured out from MathWonk's answer. How does it compare to your result?

Comment: I was having trouble working through the answer below, but I was able to duplicate your plot based on your updated answer above. In my approach, the analytic function $f(t)$ evaluates to the origin at $t=0$ and the result at each positive integer value of $t$ seems to be located on a lobe that always seem to connect back to the origin (or close to the origin) between integer values of $t$. (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL1fO.jpg).

Comment: @StevenClark Fascinating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a broad outline of a solution. The linear-fractional transformation $z\to z'=T(z)=a+ \frac{b}{z}$ can also be expressed in the format of a $2\times 2$ matrix  equation, and the iterates of this transformation then become expressed as consecutive integer powers of a matrix $M$. [linear-fractional maps as matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362607/fractional-linear-transformations-and-their-matrix-form#2362616)

In more detail, you will find that the numerator and denominator of your iterated function are the two components of the quantity $M^n V$ where $V=(1,0)$ is a $2\times 1$ column vector. Sample shown below.

[image]

The next step is to compute those matrix powers. This can be done by consulting
[powers of a general 2x2 matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548549/formula-for-powers-of-2-times-2-matrices)

In particular, use this formula, contained therein:

[image]

Finally,the interpolation you seek boils down to interpolation of integer powers of the eigenvalues   $\alpha, \beta$. For that final step you can simply use the  identity $ \alpha^n= e^{n \ln (\alpha)}$  in which $n$ is now free to be non-integer. Likewise for $\beta$.

Comment: (1/2) I'm not familiar with most of the math you bring up here, but here's my best interpretation so far based on Wikipedia & Wolfram: my equation $z↦a+\frac{b}{z}$ can be rewritten as $z↦\frac{a z+b}{1 z+0}$, which is the same as the standard form of a linear fractional transformation $z↦\frac{a z+b}{c z+d}$ with $c=1$ and $d=0$. This corresponds to the matrix $(\begin{matrix} a & b \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix})$. Asking WolframAlpha for the eigenvalues of that matrix gives $λ_2=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+4b}+a}{2}$, which is the value to which my continued fractions converge, plus its negative inverse $λ_1$.

Comment: (2/2) However, powers of $λ_1$ or $λ_2$ do not give the successive levels of the continued fractions, which I think is what you are saying should happen. Asking WolframAlpha for the diagonalization of the matrix gives three new matrices made up of variations of $λ$, but I'm not sure what to do with them. Can you elaborate a bit more on what to do here?

Comment: I updated my answer with additional references that I hope you will find useful.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about this step: "After you diagonalize that matrix using its eigendecomposition you should find that the interpolation you seek boils down to interpolation of integer powers of the eigenvalues"? I have no experience with linear algebra and I have only a modest understanding of how to work with matrices. I have no idea what diagonalizing and eigendecomposition are, but it sounds like they are the most important parts of getting to what I actually want, yet you just gloss over them. I'm working on researching these concepts now, but that could take a while on my own.

Comment: OK. Latest edit eliminates as much linear algebra as possible and highlights the key equation more explicitly.

Comment: I realized I could get WolframAlpha to handle the linear-algebra side of things and get an answer even if I don't understand what it's doing under the hood, so to speak.